# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, make

I am trying to build dmenu but I got this error.

dmenu build options:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Os -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -DVERSION="4.9" -DXINERAMA
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXinerama -lfontconfig -lXft
CC = cc
cc -o dmenu dmenu.o drw.o util.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXinerama -lfontconfig -lXft
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:26: dmenu] Error 1
```

Comment: Your questions is missing some, perhaps important, information, like the Ubuntu version and architecture you're building on, and what you already tried to solve this. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how you can improve your posts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume here that you're using a fairly recent AMD64 PC and *Ubuntu* release.

1. Make sure you have the appropriate development packages installed; for *libXinerama* that would be `libxinerama-dev`.
2. On *Ubuntu 20.04* for `amd64` the libs are installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` according to the [filelist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libxinerama-dev/filelist). You can check that with

   ```
   $ ldconfig -p | grep Xine
   ```

Thus the adaption you need to apply is extending the `LDFLAGS` after you've installed the development package(s):

```
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lX11 -lXinerama -lfontconfig -lXft
```

If that still doesn't work, edit your question and add the appropriate details, and also which package and manual you're using as a basis for your efforts.